# Is there a decent, real, question we can use in the Tour?

Tags: discussion, tour

On the [tour](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) page, our example question is currently about unicorns and daisies. Do we have any questions that are eligible for replacing this placeholder? If so, could we use that instead?

As an aside, the example answer is wrong. The correct answer is to use lion statues near the daisies. Anyone that knows anything about unicorns should know that [lions and unicorns are enemies](http://www.allaboutunicorns.com/lion-and-unicorn.php).

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question asked before here, but I can't find it. Oh well :) But hey, you should feature-request a change to the accepted answer for that question on Meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Fraid not.

> There are currently no viable question candidates for the About page.

Answer (score 5):

This is the same issue that [Software Recommendations faced](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/888): the site's expectations of questions/answers are pretty much incompatible with those of the Tour. In two years of existence, they got [*two* questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/92078/possible-about-questions) that qualify for the tour. For Hardware Recommendations, this query comes up empty.

Another query, [Possible tour questions and near misses](http://data.stackexchange.com/hardwarerecs/query/342500/possible-tour-questions-and-near-misses), identifies one "near miss": that question will be eligible if it gets the score of 5, one more *short* answer (under 400 characters), and at least one comment on one of the two short answers.